# async/await, setTimeout, and promise taking too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am building a sorting visualizer, my goal is to visualize each comparison between elements.
First I tried the below code without any delays, it executed instantly and nothing can be visualized. So I added an async/await/delay functionality, however, after timing the delay function, it is taking 16ms on average, when I needed it to be around 5ms.

So I am stumped, and I do not know why its taking so long to execute.

```
export const bubbleSort = async (
  array: stick[],
  setArray: (array: stick[]) => void
) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      console.log(i, j);
      array[j].color = "green";
      array[j + 1].color = "green";
      setArray([...array]);
      await delay(1);
      if (array[j].value > array[j + 1].value) swap(array, j, j + 1);
      setArray([...array]);
      array[j].color = "black";
      array[j + 1].color = "black";
      setArray([...array]);
    }
  }
};

const swap = (array: stick[], i: number, j: number) => {
  let temp = array[i].value;
  array[i].value = array[j].value;
  array[j].value = temp;
};

const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: The spread operator tends to be pretty slow if you’re working with a large array, try to remove it.

Comment: You could delay every second/third/fourth iteration until it’s a suitable speed

Comment: I think setInterval is what your looking for. The bubble algorithm can execute immediately, then with the resulting dataset use setInterval with perhaps a 1000ms interval to render the visualisation every second until you run out of data, then just clear the interval

Comment: @KyleLambert Given this is react, and the array is being modified, you can hardly avoid the copying. But for a visualisation, the array won't be huge anyway

Comment: That said, doing multiple `setArray([...array]);` calls without a delay in between is pointless, react will only render the last state anyway - and it may fail to batch them, so it unnecessarily re-renders

Answer (score -1):

Some things you can do to improve the speed:

- Don't execute `console.log` in the inner loop
- Don't call `setArray` more than you will allow for a render to actually visualise: so only once per call of `delay`
- Make `delay` dependent on `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`, because `setTimeout` puts its callback on a queue that has less priority than the queue that gets paint events, and because `setTimeout` employs a minimum delay.

So:

```
export const bubbleSort = async (
  array: stick[],
  setArray: (array: stick[]) => void
) => {
  await paint();
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      array[j].color = "green";
      array[j + 1].color = "green";
      setArray([...array]);
      await paint();
      if (array[j].value > array[j + 1].value) swap(array, j, j + 1);
      array[j].color = "black";
      array[j + 1].color = "black";
    }
  }
};

const swap = (array: stick[], i: number, j: number) => {
  let temp = array[i].value;
  array[i].value = array[j].value;
  array[j].value = temp;
};

const paint = () => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);
```

#### But still:

On many configurations (depending on monitor, operating system, and browser) the paint frequency is 60Hz, which comes down to an interval of ... (suprise) 16.666ms! You can check the refresh rate of your configuration [here](https://www.testufo.com/refreshrate).

If it turns out that this is your situation, then you'll have to call `delay/paint` fewer times:

```
export const bubbleSort = async (
  array: stick[],
  setArray: (array: stick[]) => void
) => {
  await paint();
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      array[j].color = "green";
      array[j + 1].color = "green";
      if (i % 4 == 0) {
          setArray([...array]);
          await paint();
      }
      if (array[j].value > array[j + 1].value) swap(array, j, j + 1);
      array[j].color = "black";
      array[j + 1].color = "black";
    }
  }
  setArray([...array]);
};

const swap = (array: stick[], i: number, j: number) => {
  let temp = array[i].value;
  array[i].value = array[j].value;
  array[j].value = temp;
};

const paint = () => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);
```